# class path resource [default/jdbc.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

I think I'm making good progress with a large Maven Multimode Project I've inherited. I'm a complete beginner in all regards with Tomcat and JAVA projects so please excuse my naivety. I believe I need to know how to define the location of my JDBC properties config but I don't where to start looking to be honest.

I am trying to run my project via terminal with "mvn tomcat7:run" and receiving a severe error as noted below.

The specific error cause:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'eu.digient.billfold.support.dao.properties': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   class path resource [default/jdbc.properties] cannot be opened because
>   it does not exist

I have located this string in many of my .IML files inside the Maven project, what does the syntax mean, where is it looking for the config?

```
 <util:properties id="eu.digient.billfold.support.dao.properties"
                 location="classpath:#{systemProperties['configProfile']?:'default'}/jdbc.properties" />
```

Any tips and advice on the JBDC config would be great, I'm aware it's for defining database connection details. In this case a connection to Hibernate for JAVA which is totally new to me.

(I'm not sure how to add this as a chunk below other than via blockquote, so say if I'm missing the method for a more readable way?)

The full terminal error output:

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'eu.digient.billfold.support.dao.properties' while setting bean property 'properties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eu.digient.billfold.support.dao.properties': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [default/jdbc.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:657)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eu.digient.billfold.support.dao.properties': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [default/jdbc.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
>       ... 23 more
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [default/jdbc.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>       at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:143)
>       at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
>       at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean.createInstance(PropertiesFactoryBean.java:113)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean.createProperties(PropertiesFactoryBean.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(PropertiesFactoryBean.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
>       ... 30 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `jdbc.properties` file in `src\main\resources\default` directory

Comment: Excellent I shall try, as my project is multimode must I do this for all layers? I assume so thinking about as most layers have the "classpath:#{systemProperties['configProfile']?:'default'}/jdbc.properties" string in the IML. Is this string a standard then? I'm keen to know what it means in depth.

Comment: Sorry and do I have to setup a DB locally before running the project or does Hibernate fire this up when the project boots as part of configuration. I'm used to just connecting to an existing MYSQL DB. This project once worked before and seems to be mostly configured, it's been quite task to fix dependencies locally.

Comment: @Beloudest:  ">I do this for all layers?" - you can do this in each maven module, as long as it is assambled to an JAR and this JAR is deployed with the application. This works because "classpath:" scan in all jars. But I do not know what happen if you have more then one file with the same name and in the same folder

Comment: @Beloudest: >" I have to setup a DB locally before running the project" - In a normal Spring application Spring will start Hibernate, and therefore Spring could configure hibernate via its properties.